# best pratice for only returning some properties from an entity mvc (projection)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just wondered how you should best architect an MVC project, when some views return all the properties on an object and some return only a few.

Do you:

- Create a separate controller and view model for, say, "News Brief" for just the title and the description of news, and then another full controller for "News Total" which will return the author, related news and and features etc.
- Or should they merely be separate actions and methods? If so, the naming convention can be tricky.

Has anyone had any experience that could suggest the best way to handle this? I want it so that, when a programmer makes a change to one method, he doesn't have to think, *"but what other views is this going to mess up if I remove/ add this property?"*

Comment: I've written this https://github.com/AlexanderBrevig/ExposeOrHide for not having to create many view models. It basically enables you to black- or white list which members of a class should be included in the response. It creates a `dynamic` with just the fields you need.

Comment: Consider [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)?

Comment: Create separate action methods with different view models. That's (one of the main reasons) why view models exist!